# How to nest plugin URLs?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I would like to create a "Shell" of a Grails project that hosts functionality in plugins, with the URLs segregated by plugin name.

So the URLs for a **Blog** plugin used in the Shell project might look like: `/shell/blog/viewBlogPost`

But what I'm actually seeing is all of the plugins' controllers behave as if they are part of the shell project itself: `/shell/viewBlogPost`

Is there any way to declare that the Blog plugin's controllers be accessible only under a  `/blog` path in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Grails plugins are not able to do this. The problem is that they lack encapsulation and composability, leading to artifact conflicts:

- URL routing from plugins is simply merged together and cannot be nested
- Controllers are not namespaced
- Services are not namespaced

I opened an issue: [GRAILS-9300](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9300)

The Grails team has [tentative plans](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/wiki/Artifact-Namespaces) to address this in 2.2, by using the plugin name as a namespace for artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your plugins can register URL mappings just like the rest of your "shell" application can.

Comment: I thought UrlMappings.groovy wasn't included in the plugin, by default?

Comment: Can the Shell project define the root URL to use for each plugin?

Comment: I'm sure it can, but by default, it's not set up to work that way other than the Shell project dictating the name of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare UrlMappings in a plugin by creating a file with a name ending in UrlMappings in your plugin (e.g. `BlogPluginUrlMappings.groovy`) and these will get merged into the main application's UrlMappings. You can setup mappings starting with `/blog/` to route to your plugin's controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately Grails plugins couldn't quite do what I wanted, and I posted another answer detailing this.