# Does Grails supports Restful nested URLs?

Tags: grails

Does Grails supports Restful nested URLs like '/articles/1/comments/5' by default? If not is there any plugin for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're bound to an older release of Grails (e.g < 2.3), and the available plugins don't work out, you can use [named URL mappings](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#namedMappings) to produce an effective restful mapping.

Here's an example from a project of mine - I've left out some details, but hopefully this gets you started if you decide to give this approach a try.

In your UrlMappings.groovy

```
/** 1. Mappings can handle multiple actions depending on HTTP 
    method like Rest. Names are a little clunky, like this would
    be more appropriate as "resource" vs "showResource" but we didn't want
    potential naming conflict in future release 

    2. TODO: DRY constraints - make constraints global  
    3. make sure controllers have proper actions defined
*/

/** RESTFUL mapping for single resource */
name listResources: "/$controller" { 
  action = [GET: "list", POST: "save"] 
}
name createResource: "/$controller/create" { 
  action = [GET: "create" ] 
}
name deleteResource: "/$controller/$id?/delete" { 
  action = [POST: "delete", DELETE: "delete"] 
  constraints { id(matches: /[0-9]+/) }
}
name editResource: "/$controller/$id?/edit" { 
  action = [GET: "edit", PUT: "update", POST: "update"] 
  constraints { id(matches: /[0-9]+/) }
}
name showResource: "/$controller/$id?" { 
  action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update", POST: "update", DELETE: "delete"]
  constraints { id(matches: /[0-9]+/) }
}

/** RESTFUL mapping for CHILD with PARENT */
name listChildResources: "/$parentResource/$pid/$controller" { 
  action = [GET: "list", POST: "save"]
  constraints { pid(matches: /[0-9]+/) }
}
name createChildResource: "/$parentResource/$pid/$controller/create" {
  action = [GET: "create" ] 
  constraints { pid(matches: /[0-9]+/) }
}
name showChildResource: "/$parentResource/$pid/$controller/$id?" { 
  action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update", POST: "update", DELETE: "delete"] 
  constraints { 
    id(matches: /[0-9]+/)
    pid(matches: /[0-9]+/) 
  }
}
name editChildResource: "/$parentResource/$pid/$controller/$id?/edit" { 
  action = [GET: "edit"]
  constraints { 
    id(matches: /[0-9]+/)
    pid(matches: /[0-9]+/) 
  }
}
```

Make sure you controllers have actions and supported HTTP methods define, eg

```
static allowedMethods = [
  save: "POST", 
  update: ["POST", "PUT"], 
  delete: ["POST", "DELETE"]
]
```

Then use the mappings like so (for example lets say we have Gardens and Plants as resources).

```
//show a garden
<g:link mapping="showResource" controller="garden" 
   id="${gardenInstance.id}">${gardenInstance.name}</g:link>

//create a plant for garden
<g:link mapping="createChildResource" controller="plant" 
   params="[parentResource: 'garden', pid: gardenInstance.id]">Add Plant</g:link>

//show list of plants within a garden
<g:link mapping="listChildResources" controller="plant" 
   params="[parentResource: 'garden', pid: gardenInstance.id]">List plants for Garden</g:link>
```

Shown here it's pretty verbose, but you could put all of this into TagLib and have something like.

```
<g:restShow resource="garden" 
   id="${gardenInstance.id}">${gardenInstance.name}</g:restShow>

<g:restCreate" resource="plant" 
   parent="${gardenInstance}">Add Plant</g:restCreate>
```

Answer (score 6):

See [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/wiki/Grails-2.3%3a-REST-Improvements#nested-resources).  Nested RESTful URLs will be supported in Grails 2.3.

Comment: Thanks for the info but as you said this will be included in incoming release. Is there any plugin for that which would allow to do the same thing in Grails 2.2?

Comment: I have no idea.  I doubt it.  More info about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11657392